# How to register biometric fingerprint in flutter app

Tags: flutter, biometrics, flutter-android, android-biometric

Is there a way to register user biometric directly from flutter app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Check if the device supports biometrics

```
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';
// ···
  final LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
  // ···
    final bool canAuthenticateWithBiometrics = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
    final bool canAuthenticate =
        canAuthenticateWithBiometrics || await auth.isDeviceSupported();
```

To authenticate use

```
final bool didAuthenticate = await auth.authenticate(
    localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance',
    options: const AuthenticationOptions(biometricOnly: true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a mobile application with cordova using the Quasar CLI framework.
The aim of the application is to collect the fingerprints of the population in an area and send them to php to store them in a MySQL database.
I'd like you to tell me which npm package I can use to allow me to scan the fingerprints and capture them in binary or single text format to send to the database.

Comment: It appears you are asking the question in the answer section. If you want to ask a question please use [question section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).
Thanks.